# Template for F# and WPF (Visual Studio 2019 Community)?

Tags: f#, vsix

As a newbie to F#, I have read many references to starting a new project with the "F# Empty Windows Application (WPF)". However, the template does not show up in my Visual Studio 2019 Community edition. Downloading and installing it fails as well.

Is there a good template to start a new project in F# for WPF?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are [no templates](https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/162) because there are no designers that map XAML to F# code however you can use the following alternatives:

- You can create a C# project and build your UI and then take the XAML into an F# project by leveraging the [XAML type provider](https://github.com/fsprojects/FsXaml) which will get you the structure and types of your UI components.  There is a nice tutorial [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-wpf-application-with-f-sharp-and-fsxaml/) although I haven't tried it myself and it might be a bit old.
- You can use the C# XAML generated and do the [binding manually](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2011/september/fsharp-programming-build-mvvm-applications-in-fsharp) in an empty F# project .
- You can use the generated XAML and [Elmish.WPF](https://github.com/elmish/Elmish.WPF#getting-started-with-elmishwpf) using the MVU model which I suggested earlier.
- You can avoid XAML altogether and use [Fabulous](https://fsprojects.github.io/Fabulous/Fabulous.XamarinForms/) to build the UI programatically. This uses Xamarin though. This has however, some nice project templates and also follows the MVU model.